# Classification according to unique values \

Tags: r, loops

I have  a data frame named as Records having 2 vectors Rank and Name

```
Rank     Name  
1        Ashish     
1        Ashish  
2        Ashish  
3        Mark  
4        Mark  
1        Mark  
3        Spencer  
2        Spencer  
1        Spencer  
2        Mary  
4        Joseph
```

I want that every name should be placed in either 1, 2 ,3 or 4 tag depending on their occurrence and uniqueness:

I want to create a new vector which will be named as Tagging

So The output should be:

> Rank 1 has three unique elements Mark Spencer and Ashish so the tag is 1 for all three.
>
> Rank 2 has  one unique records which is Mary as Ashish has already been assigned  tag 1 so Mary is tagged  as 2.
>
> Rank 3 has no unique records as Spencer and Mark has already been assigned 1 so I cannot tag 3 to anybody.
>
> Rank 4 has one unique record Joseph so he gets tagged as 4.

Let me know which function can help me do this.

I do not want to use looping as this is 1000000 row database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below solution follows the principle that the highest Rank of a person is going to be that person's tag too.**

```
tbl <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
Rank     Name  
1        Ashish     
1        Ashish  
2        Ashish  
3        Mark  
4        Mark  
1        Mark  
3        Spencer  
2        Spencer  
1        Spencer  
2        Mary  
4        Joseph   
')
```

**Ordering the *'tbl'* dataframe by Rank**

```
tbl_ord <- tbl[with(tbl,order(Rank)),]
```

**Removing multiple occurrence of name within same Rank**

```
> name_ord<- tbl_ord[duplicated(tbl_ord$Rank),]
> name_ord
   Rank    Name
2     1  Ashish
6     1    Mark
9     1 Spencer
8     2 Spencer
10    2    Mary
7     3 Spencer
11    4  Joseph
```

**Displaying unique Names**

```
#name_ord[unique(name_ord$Name),] #this will work too

> name_ord[!duplicated(name_ord$Name),]
   Rank    Name
2     1  Ashish
6     1    Mark
9     1 Spencer
10    2    Mary
11    4  Joseph
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `setkey` function of `data.table` package and `unique`:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(Rank=c(1,1,2,3,4,1,3,2,1,2,4), Name=c(rep("Ashish", 3), rep("Mark", 3), rep("Spencer", 3), "Mary", "Joseph"))
setkey(dt, Rank, Name)
dt<-unique(dt)
setkey(dt, Name)
dt<-unique(dt) # works because of the above setkey call which sorted it
setkey(dt, Rank) # if you want to order them by Rank again
```